# Documentdb stored proc cross partition query

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have a stored procedure which gives me a document count ([count.js on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/Count.js)). I have partitioned my collection. Due to this, I now have to pass the partition key in as an option to run the stored procedure.

Can and how should I enable crosspartition queries in the stored procedure (ie, `collection(EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true)`) so that I don't have to specify the partition key?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do fan-out stored procedure execution in DocumentDB. The run against a single partition. I ran into this dilemma when trying to switch to partitioned collections and had to make some adjustments. Here are some options:

1. Download a 1 for every record and sum/count them client-side
2. Rerun the stored procedure for each unique partition key. In my case, this was not as bad as it sounds since the partition key is a tenantID and I only have a dozen of those and only expect a few hundred max.
3. I'm not sure about this one since I haven't tried it with partitioned collections, but each query now returns the resource usage of the collection in the x-ms-resource-usage header. That header has a documentsSize sub-header. You could use that divided by the average size of your documents to get an approximate count. There may even be a count record in that header information by now.
4. Also, there is an x-ms-item-count header but I'm not sure how that behaves. If you send a query for all the records in the entire partitioned collection and set the max-item-count to 1, you'll only get back one record and it shouldn't cost you a lot in RUs, but I don't know how that header behaves. Does it return a 1 in that case? Or does it return the total number of documents all the pages of the query would eventually return if you bothered to request every page. A quick experiment should confirm this.

Comment: I am dealing with around 19k partitions having arounud 70 million records. So, will have to affect the performance :(  @Larry

Comment: Option 2 is definitely out for you. I suspect you meant 19K unique partition KEYS. You have no way of knowing how many partitions are actually in use because DocumentDB manages that.

Comment: 1 is the best option. Native aggregation support is in private preview and will be available H1 2017 per DocumentDB team: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333963-add-support-for-aggregate-functions-like-count-su.

Answer (score -1):

Below you can find some example code that should allow you to read all records cross partion. The magic is inside the `doForAll` function, and at the top you can see how it is called.

```
// SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE
function sample(prefix) {

    var share = { counter: 0, hasEntityName : 0, isXXX: 0, partitions: {}, prefix };

    doForAll({
        filter: function limiter(record){
            if (record && record.entityName === 'XXX') return true;
            else return false;
        },
        callback: function handleRecord(record) {
            //Keep track of this partition...
            let partitionKey = record.partitionKey;
            if (share.partitions[partitionKey])
                share.partitions[partitionKey]++;
            else 
                share.partitions[partitionKey] = 1;

            //update some counters...
            share.counter++;
            if (record.entityName !== undefined) share.hasEntityName++;
            if (record.entityName === 'XXX') share.isXXX++;
        },
        finaly: function whenAllIsDone() {
            console.log("counter = " + share.counter + ". ");
            console.log("has entity name: "+ share.hasEntityName+ ". ")
            console.log("is XXX: " + share.isXXX+ ". ")
            var parts = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(share.partitions)
            console.log("partition keys: " + parts.length + " ...");

            getContext()
                .getResponse()
                .setBody(share);
        }
    });


    //The magic function...
    //also see: https://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/Collection.html
    function doForAll(task, ctoken) {

        if (!task) throw "Expected one parameter of type: { filter?: (rec?)=>boolean, callback?: (rec?) => void, finaly?: () => void }";
        //Note:
        //the "__" symbol is an alias for var collection = getContext().getCollection(); = aliased by __

        var result = getContext()
            .getCollection()
            .chain()
                .filter(task.filter || function (rec) { return true; })
                .map(task.callback || function (rec) { return undefined; })
            .value({ continuation: ctoken }, function afterBatchCallback (err, feed, options) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (options.continuation)
                    doForAll(task, options.continuation);
                else if (task.finaly)
                    task.finaly();
            });

        if (!result.isAccepted)
            throw "catastrophic failure";
    }

}
```

PS: it may to know how the data looks like that is used for the example.
This is an example of such a document:

```
{ 
    "id": "123",
    "partitionKey": "PART_1",
    "entityName": "EXAMPLE_ENTITY",
    "veryInterestingInfo": "The 'id' property is also the collections id, the 'partitionKey' property happens to be the collections partition key, and all the records in this collection have a 'entityName' property which contains a (non-unique) string"
}
```

Comment: Failed with: "Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys other than the one for which client request was submitted."