# Cosmos DB + Partition Key + Store procedure

Tags: xamarin, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Xamarin Mobile application that access a Comos DB collection on Azure.

My wish is to have all a SQL query inside a store procedure, that way if needed I can change the SQL query server side, without modifying the mobile app !

So, for now I have a simple stored proc. with a "select *" clause. The problem is that to execute the stored proc. I must provide a partition key !

It is clearly described in the documentation, see here : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#database-program-transactions

It is not really practical, executing the stored proc. over my 235 possibles partitions keys !

Do you see the issue ? Any idea of the best practice ?

Edit : I have found this post, but it does not help a lot :
[Documentdb stored proc cross partition query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764375/documentdb-stored-proc-cross-partition-query)

Comment: Can't you just set the `CrossPartitionQuery` option to `true` when you execute the stored proc?

Comment: @NickChapsas it should work from what I understabd, I haven't tried from Xamarin directly. For now I try to test my stored proc. from the Azure portal but it ask for a key ! Not sure it is possible to set such flag on the portal :-(

Comment: @Krysalid - a stored procedure is scoped to a single partition. You cannot do a cross-partition call to a stored procedure. But this is where it's important to model your database correctly. For example, why do you need to "`SELECT *`"? Why do you need data all at once from 235 partitions? If this is really a common use case, then you'll neither need to make multiple calls or remodel your collection with a different partition strategy.

Comment: An example, I have a collection 'user' and the partition key is 'CountryIsoCode'. I'm searching all the friends of this guy... but of course, I don't know in which country they are. Do you see the problem @DavidMakogon

Comment: @Krysalid - well, without knowing any other details of your app, it looks like `CountryIsoCode` isn't an optimum partition key, since it causes issues with one of your fundamental query requirements. Or, it might require you to store "friend" relationships differently (perhaps in a different collection) to support such searching, while at the same time preserving the country-based partitioning you chose.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon, but what does it violate ? and so, what should I use as a key, something that make sense, any idea ? Imagine I do a facebook clone by example, what can be my key ?