# SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.UserId FROM root c) AS t not working

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In a Cosmos DB stored procedure, I'm using a inline sql query to try and retrieve the distinct count of a particular user id.

I'm using the SQL API for my account. I've run the below query in Query Explorer in my Cosmos DB account and I know that I should get a count of 10 (There are 10 unique user ids in my collection):

```sql
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.UserId FROM root c) AS t
```

However when I run this in the Stored Procedure portal, I either get 0 records back or 18 records back (total number of documents). The code for my Stored Procedure is as follows:

```
function GetDistinctCount() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.UserId  FROM root c) AS t',      
        function(err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (!feed || !feed.length) {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                var body = {code: 404, body: "no docs found"}
                response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
            } else {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                var body = {code: 200, body: feed[0]}
                response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
            }
        }
    )
}
```

After looking at various feedback forums and documentation, I don't think there's an elegant solution for me to do this as simply as it would be in normal SQL.

**the UserId is my partition key** which I'm passing through in my C# code and when I test it in the portal, so there's no additional parameters that I need to set when calling the Stored Proc. I'm calling this Stored Proc via C# and adding any further parameters will have an effect on my tests for that code, so I'm keen not to introduce any parameters if I can.

Comment: If you can share a simple repro repo on GitHub w/ your C# code, it might be easier to give an answer. It definitely matters how you invoke the stored procedure & how you set up your collection.

Comment: You could mark your answer to end this case,thank you.

Comment: Done :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that returns the result I need. My stored procedure now looks like this:

```
function GetPaymentCount() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT DISTINCT VALUE(doc.UserId) from root doc' ,
        {pageSize:-1 },

        function(err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (!feed || !feed.length) {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                var body = {code: 404, body: "no docs found"}
                response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
            } else {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                var body = {code: 200, body: JSON.stringify(feed.length)}
                response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Essentially, I changed the pageSize parameter to -1 which returned all the documents I knew would be returned in the result. I have a feeling that this will be more expensive in terms of RU/s cost, but it solves my case for now.

If anyone has more efficient alternatives, please comment and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by that you missed setting partition key for your stored procedure.

Please see the statements in the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs):

[image]

And this:

[image]

So,when you execute a stored procedure under a partitioned collection, you need to pass the partition key param. It's necessary! (Also this case explained this:[Documentdb stored proc cross partition query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764375/documentdb-stored-proc-cross-partition-query))

Back to your question,you never pass any partition key, equals you pass an `null` value or `""` value for partition key, so it outputs no data because you don't have any userId equals null or "".

[image]

My advice:
You could use normal Query SDK to execute your sql, and set the `enableCrossPartitionQuery: true` which allows you scan entire collection without setting partition key. Please refer to this tiny sample:[Can't get simple CosmosDB query to work via Node.js - but works fine via Azure's Query Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125719/cant-get-simple-cosmosdb-query-to-work-via-node-js-but-works-fine-via-azures)

Comment: I'm passing the value of the partition key in my C# code and when I'm running in the portal. I'll update my question to stress that now

Comment: @WillV If you pass the specific value of partition key, the result will limited in that specific partition. I think it's not your want.